# Writing to csv file. ' ; ' for next column is not working

Tags: php, laravel, csv

I am trying to write my survey out come to a csv file. I would like to get it like so:

```
Question     Answer
Question1    Answer1
Question2    Answer2
Question3    Answer3
Question4    Answer4
Question5    Answer5
```

So above it comes out in 2 separate columns, but below it comes out in one column.
It comes out as:

```
Question           Answer
Question1;Answer1
Question2;Answer2
Question3;Answer3
Question4;Answer4
Question5;Answer5
```

So the ; for the next column does work for the header question answer but not for the actual questions and answers. Wondering why and what I am doing wrong.

```
$fileName = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
    fputcsv($fileName, ['Vraag;' . 'Antwoord']);
    foreach($newSurvey['data']['formCategories'] as $category) {
        foreach($category['formQuestions'] as $question) {
            $id = $question['id'];
            $arr = [$question['name'] . '; ' . $request->$id];
            $vraag = [$question['name'] . ';'];
            $antwoord = [$request->$id . ';'];
            if($request->$id) {
                fputcsv($fileName, $arr);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose($fileName);
```

I would really like to know why it doesn't work, and what to improve on the code.

Sorry for any grammar and spelling mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [`fputcsv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php), there is an option to define what the separator used in the data should be (the third parameter).  So rather than add this to your data, you should just specify the `;` as the delimeter...

```
$fileName = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($fileName, ['Vraag','Antwoord'], ';');
foreach($newSurvey['data']['formCategories'] as $category) {
    foreach($category['formQuestions'] as $question) {
        $id = $question['id'];
        $arr = [$question['name'],$request->$id];
        $vraag = [$question['name']];
        $antwoord = [$request->$id];
        if($request->$id) {
            fputcsv($fileName, $arr, ';');
        }
    }
}
fclose($fileName);
```

Comment: Wow, I did not know that. Thank you for telling me